# How can I disable some of the tabs of the moreNavigationController of my UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using XCode 13.0, Swift 5.5 and Storyboard. This is a mobile app for iPhone with iOS 15.

I have altogether 7 tabs, all of them with icons. I have 4 tabs and a "More" tab in the tab bar of my app.
3 additional tabs show up after the user clicks on the "More" tab. I'd like the first 2 of these additional tabs to be disabled. They need to be grey coloured and when the user clicks on any of these 2, I'd like to app to do nothing (not to show any page, not to navigate anywhere). I'm using the original UITabBarController  and moreNavigationController defined by Apple, I didn't subclass any of them.
On my storyboard I added 2 UIViewControllers to these 2 disabled tabs, but I set them disabled this way:

[image: Disbaled tabbar icons]

This didn't work at all. When the user clicks on the 2 disabled tabs, they show 2 empty ViewControllers. I'd expect them not to show anything.

I also tried accessing the moreNavigationController's tabs from the page my UITabBarController first opens. I tried setting these 2 tabs disabled programmatically. However I didn't manage to access these 2 tabs, I only manage to access the main tabs that show up in the tab bar (I don't need to access these). How can I disable and colour grey the tabs that show up after clicking on the More tab?

```
let moreControllerItems = tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.toolbarItems
    
if let tabArray = moreControllerItems {
   let tabBarItem1 = tabArray[0]
   let tabBarItem2 = tabArray[1]

   tabBarItem1.isEnabled = false
   tabBarItem2.isEnabled = false
}`
```

This code doesn't work, the moreControllerItems variable is nil. The tabBarController variable isn't nil, I can access my UITabBarController from here, but it doesn't help me much.
I googled this issue lots of different ways but I couldn't find the solution. Any help would be appreciated. I really need to solve this, please write a comment if you have any idea how to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tabBar items from TabBarController.

```
class TabVC: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func disableTabBar(itemNo: Int) {
    if let items = tabBar.items, itemNo < items.count {
        items[itemNo].isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

And you can access this function from
any child Viewcontroller attached to TabBarController

```
class MoreVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let tabBarVC = tabBarController as? TabVC {
        tabBarVC.disableTabBar(itemNo: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Antony for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work :( I tried it, it'd only work if I was trying to disable one of the first 4 tabbar items. I have 7 tabbar items altogether. I'm trying to disable the 5th and 6th tabbar items. The last 3 tabbar items are part of moreNavigationController. This is the way UITabBarController works when there're more tabs than 4 in an app. moreNavigationController is apple's own class, I didn't define it. I'm using apple's original UITabBarController, I didn't subclass it. Do you know how I can disable some of the tabs of moreNavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

In short: You cannot disable it. If you want to disable the item in the More Viewcontroller, you have to use a custom Viewcontroller in the fifth Tab

I am explaining here why we cannot do it and what limitations we have.

Apple will show the More tab if items are more than five in the UITabBarController. And more tab holds the UINavigationController which is attached to a kind of UIMoreListController. you can check by

```
print moreNavigationController.viewControllers[0]
```

UIMoreListController is not accessible. In your case, the remaining three items are listed in the UIMoreListController. Although we can still access the Viewcontroller's tabBarItem and we can disable it. You can check by clicking the edit option.

[image]
[image]

But still, users can click on it as long as it is in the UIMoreListController. Because we are not interacting with the tabBar instead we are interacting with the items on the list. Users can't click once you move the item to any of the first four positions using the edit option in the MoreViewcontroller.

[image]
[image]